# How to create a Function Loop that fills an empty dataframe when called

Tags: r, data-science

I am creating a lm loop function with outcomes, covariates and an exposure.
This loops creates the lm output and then puts it into an empty data frame. However, when I call the function the dataframe does not get created when I put the creation of the empty dataframe inside of the function. When I put the create of the dataframe outside the function and run it it just creates an empty dataframe that is not filled. I was wondering what the best way to fix this was. Below is my code:

```
outcomes<- c(out1,out2,out3)
exposure <-c(exp1,exp2,exp3)
my_covariates <- c(cov1,cov2,cov3)

reg_func <- function(data = ads, exposure, my_covariates, outcomes)
{
  #creates empty dataframe
  myreg_data <- data.frame()

  for (i in seq_along(outcomes))
  {
     for (j in seq_along(exposure))
  {

    mylm <- lm(formula(paste(outcomes[i], " ~ ", paste(my_covariates, 
    collapse = " + "), " + " ,paste(exposure[j]))), data = ads)
    ctable<-as.data.frame(coef(summary(mylm)))
    ctable
    dsa<-as.data.frame(cbind(ctable,Variable = rownames(ctable),
                         Outcome = outcomes[i],
                         Exposure = exposure[j],
                         Model="Cont.LR",
                         Model_n = paste(length(mylm$residuals))))
                          names(dsa)[4] <- "Pvalue"
                          rownames(dsa)<-NULL
                          myreg_data <- rbind(myreg_data,dsa)
                           return(myreg_data)
    }}}


           reg_func(data = ads, exposure = exposure, my_covariates = 
           my_covariates, outcomes = outcomes)
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so calling it has no effect.

Comment: I am very sorry I did not put that into my sample code I will edit that. Even when I return my data it does not create a permeant data frame object

Comment: Even if your function does return something, you would lose that return value if you don't assign it to a variable, something which your calling code doesn't do. Any local variables defined in your function are lost when the function is finished executing, and the returned value is not automatically moved to the global environment.

Comment: I think it would help if you look into the difference between side-effect and functional programming. What you are doing (incorrectly) is "side-effect" where the value returned by a function call is unimportant to you. Examples of functions that *should* work in side-effect are saving data to disk (`write.csv`, ...). However, when I call a function whose purpose is (to me) creating a data.frame, I want to control where it goes. I can call it once and store into `df1`, then call it again and store into `df2`. Writing the function, you should not care about this *where*, just the frame.

Comment: In R, most functions operate in a functional role without side-effect. If ever I use a function that modifies my global environment without my express intent ... I'll rewrite the function and drop that package as fast as I can. Functions that operate in side-effect are often not *reproducible*, meaning that it might work one time, but not the next, and the problem is something outside of the function's environment.

Comment: Long story short (too late), do not assume or try to make your function save an object to the global environment; it is almost always the wrong approach that will handcuff you at best and break many things at worst. Create the frame internally and `return` it.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the detailed account of the theory behind these things. I am self taught so I often have trouble with what is going on behind the scenes. In this case, if I want to save myreg_data as a global variable, do I do that with simplly myreg_data <-return(myreg_data)?

Comment: As the edited questions currently stands, you need to move the `return` statement outside of the `for` loops.

Comment: @danY When I do this, I get the dataframe in my viewer but not saved globally. How would I assign it to a global dataframe when I call the function?

Comment: `result_data_frame <- reg_func(...all_your_args...)`

Comment: @danY WHen I do this, how can I call the function later if I have the output of the function set to a dataframe instead of the name of the function?

Comment: You created a function with `reg_fun <- function(...args...)`.  You can now call `reg_func` anytime you like with any args.  When you call your function with a _specific_ set of args, you probably want to save that particular result from that one function call, and that's what `some_new_df <- reg_fun(...specific args...)` does.